# How to deploy a PHP application from ec2 instance?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-applications, yii

I have created an ec2 instance and I need to deploy my php-yii application on it. I have uploaded the entire code base to the server and I have connected it with my RDS instance holding my MYSQL database. I have setup a LAMP stack for the server. I have also configured the Network Interfaces and Security Groups and I'm able to access my files in the server from outside.
How will I deploy my yii application in this setup? Should I use beanstalk for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the application to the /var/www/html folder and it launches automatically. Also remove the index.html already present in that folder.